# How to iterate an array and check if there is a match in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have a variable that I need to check if it matches one of the keys from the array and get its value in jquery.

**JS**

```
var t = 30;
var obj = { 10: 1, 20 : 2, 30: 3, 40: 4, 50 : 5, 60: 6 };

$.each(obj, function(key, value){
   if ( t == key ) {
      alert(value);
   }
});
```

I appreciate it!

Comment: your so sample works right? what is wrong with it?

Comment: I get no alert box

Comment: Never mind. It does work!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code actually works above. Are you perhaps trying to use vanilla javascript instead of the jQuery solution you have? Here's one option you could use if you aren't using jQuery:

```html
<script>
  var t = 30;
  var obj = {
    10: 1,
    20: 2,
    30: 3,
    40: 4,
    50: 5,
    60: 6
  };

  for (var instance in obj) {
    if (instance == t){
         alert(obj[instance])
    }
  }
</script>
```

You can clean up the loop further by using the following:

```
for (var instance in obj) {
    instance == t ? alert(obj[instance]) : '' 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For check, a value/key use this function if you want to find a value with value use `type = 1` if search for key then use `type = 0`.

```
 var obj = {
    10: 1,
    20: 2,
    30: 3,
    40: 4,
    50: 5,
    60: 6
};

var find = function(input, target,type){
    var found;
    for (var prop in input) {
    if(type === 1)
    {
        if(input[prop] == target){
        found = prop;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(prop == target){
        found = prop;
        }
    }

    };

    return found;
};
var t =  5; // Value to found in array
var found = find(obj, t ,1); // For Value Check only key return

if(found){
    alert(found);
}

t =  30; // key to found in array

var found = find(obj, t  ,0); // For key Check only key return

if(found){
    alert(found);
}
```

> Note: This function returns only key for both type if you want the
>   value then use `obj[found]`.